# How to dynamically set textbox values in VB6

Tags: vb6

I would like to dynamically set some textbox values with database values.

I have tried to use something similar to below but I get the following compile error:
Can't assign to read only property. The **.name =** is highlighted.

Is it possible to assign the textbox values in this manner?

```
Dim x As Integer
 For x = 1 To 30
 Form1.RS.Fields(x).Name = RS.Fields(x).Value
Next
```

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically create controls? Or just set the text of them?

Comment: I'm trying to set the text of them, that's it. Thanks!

Comment: It's been a loong time since I've coded in VB6 so can't recall offhand, but if there's a `.text` property, use that instead of `.name`.

Comment: Thanks J! I think I may have Eddie's code working.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how come you're using old school VB6 and not VB.NET? =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using controls collection of the form :

```
Dim x As Integer
For x = 1 To 30
   Form1.Controls(RS.Fields(x).Name).Text = RS.Fields(x).Value
Next
```

Comment: Eddie, it looks like this may work. I have to modify some of my columns, but I was able to get this working for one column. I'll accept after the accept timeout resets.

Comment: Eddie, question. I also have a couple of checkboxes on the form. The loop seems to halt when it reaches the first checkbox. Is there a way to check a checkbox if there is an integer value of 1 in the field? I've looked all over for the `Controls` function but I'm not finding too much documentation on VB6

Answer (score 2):

As a takeoff on Eddi's answer, here's code that allows for multiple control types on the form:

```
Dim x As Integer

For x = 1 To 30
   If TypeOf Me.Controls(RS.Fields(x).Name) Is TextBox Then
      Me.Controls(RS.Fields(x).Name).Text = RS.Fields(x).Value
   ElseIf TypeOf Me.Controls(RS.Fields(x).Name) Is CheckBox Then
      Me.Controls(RS.Fields(x).Name).Value = _
         IIf(RS.Fields(x).Value = 1, vbChecked, vbUnchecked)
   End If
Next
```

One shortcoming of the above code is the loss of intellisense.  You can structure the code like the following so it is strongly-typed, which has a number of benefits including intellisense:

```
Dim tb As TextBox
Dim cb As CheckBox
Dim x As Integer

For x = 1 To 30
   If TypeOf Me.Controls(RS.Fields(x).Name) Is TextBox Then
      Set tb = Me.Controls(RS.Fields(x).Name)
      tb.Text = RS.Fields(x).Value
   ElseIf TypeOf Me.Controls(RS.Fields(x).Name) Is CheckBox Then
      Set cb = Me.Controls(RS.Fields(x).Name)
      cb.Value = IIf(RS.Fields(x).Value = 1, vbChecked, vbUnchecked)
   End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an array of `Text1` textboxes indexed from 1 to 30, you can use:

```
Dim iCounter As Integer
For iCounter = 1 To 30
   ' Check that counter is within the bounds of the Text1 array
   If iCounter >= Text1.LBound And iCounter <= Text1.UBound Then
       Text1(iCounter).Text = RS.Fields(iCounter).Value
   End If
Next
```

There's extra code here to check that the counter is within the range of the Text1 array. The Text1 array could be gaps (missing items) in between its LBound and UBound values so it's not perfect. For example you could delete Text1(13) and still have LBound = 1 and UBound = 30. The easiest way is to check for error '340', if you decide to add that. Since you are building the UI you can simply remove any gaps.

Using an array of Textbox controls lets you share common code like the following, which highlights the text when the cursor enters the textbox:

```
Private Sub Text1_GotFocus(Index As Integer)
    With Text1(Index)
        .SelStart = 0
        .SelLength = Len(.Text)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Etienne, thanks for the help. Unfortunately, the textbox names are all different, so this wouldn't be of too much help, but hopefully it will be useful to someone else with a similar issue.